# Pivot Table for Wagtail Form Builder for Polling and Votes purpose

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to use **[Wagtail Form Builder](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html)** for **Voting and Polling** purpose, and use **[HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/)** to display the results interactively on webpage.

the problems is that Wagtail **`FormSubmission`** class only stores information of each vote.

```
| vote user | question 1 | question 2 |
| jason     | A          |  C         |
| lily      |   D        |   B        |
```

But I want to get information like:
How many users voted for A, B, C, D for Question 1, 2 respectively, and What are those users.  Similar to do a Pivot Table for the **`FormSubmission`** results.

I understand I can do a **QuerySet API Aggregation** to get what I want, but I do not want to do this `expensive` manipulation every time when user visit the webpage.

I am thinking about using `class-level` attributes to achieve this.

**Q: I am wondering what is the best practice to store those **aggregation** results in DB and update accordingly every time a **Vote** is submitted?**

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail form builder is not really suitable for this task. It's designed to allow non-programmers to construct forms for simple data collection - where it just needs to be stored and retrieved, with no further processing - without having to know how to define a Django model. To achieve this, all the data is stored in the FormSubmission model in a single field as JSON text, so that the same model can be re-used for any form. Since this isn't a format that the database engine understands natively, there's no way to perform complex queries on it efficiently - the only way is to unpack each submission individually and run calculations on it in Python code, which is going to be less efficient than any queryset functionality.

Instead, I would recommend writing a custom Django app for this. [The tutorial in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial02/) is a polls app, which should give you some idea of the way to go about it, but in short, you'll most likely need three models: a Question model containing the text of each question, an AnswerChoice model where each item is one of the possible answers for one question, and a Response model indicating which AnswerChoice a given user has chosen. With these models, you'll be able to perform queries such as "how many users answered A for question 1" with a queryset expression such as:

```
Response.objects.filter(question=1, answer_choice='A').count()
```

Comment: thanks for reply. As this polling & voting functions are not frequently used (though data analysis and visualization will be a major task for my website), I am reluctant to create a separate app for this. I probably will have a dedicated Python code to fulfill **generic statistic requirements**, not only for this polling & voting, but also for other data analysis as well.